# Cannot been displayed all the project options in visual studio 2019 team explorer after connecting with azure devops project

Tags: azure, devops

After creating project in azure devops and then when I connecting azure repos with visual studio 2019. I cannot see all required options located at team explorer in project section.

[[image: Cannot see all the options showing in the following picture][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQZns.png)

instead showing like the following

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In visual Studio 2019 go to menu **Tools > Options > Preview Features** then uncheck **New Git user experience**